# Helm error from Jenkins pipeline: "Error: no objects visited"

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to implement a couple subcharts in our CI/CD pipeline but my `helm upgrade --install` command keeps returning the error message:

> Release "testing" does not exists. Installing now.
> Error: no objects visisted

It seems like this is a pretty general error message so I'm not quite sure what it's pointing to. Any suggestions/hints/tips etc would be greatly appreciated.

The folder structure of my helm directory is as follows:

```
  deployment
  |-helm
    |testing
    ||charts
      |application
        |-templates
        | |-deployment.yaml
        |-.helmignore
        |-Chart.yaml
        |-value.yaml
      |configuration
       |-templates
       | |-configmap.yaml
       | |-secrets.yaml
       |-.helmignore
       |-Chart.yaml
       |-values.yaml
    ||-Chart.yaml
    ||-values.yaml
```

Dependencies are defined as follows:

**testing/Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v2
name: testing
description: subchart demo
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

**testing/values.yaml**

```
application:
  enabled: true

#disable configuration for easier debugging
configuration:
  enabled: false
```

**configuration/Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v2
name: configuration
description: subchart demo
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

**application/Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v2
name: application
description: subchart demo
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

**application/deployment.yaml**

```
 {{- range $k, $v := .Values.region }}
  apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ .countryCode | lower }}-deployment
    name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ .countryCode | lower }}-deployment
    namespace: {{ $.Values.global.namespace }}
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ .countryCode | lower }}-deployment
      spec:
        containers:
          - image: {{ $.Values.image_name }}
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-{{ .countryCode | lower }}-deployment
---
{{- end }}
```

**application/values.yaml**

```
image_name: image_name

config:
  enabled: true

region:
  - countryCode: US

volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /app/config
    name: app-config-volume

volumes:
  - name: app-config-volume
    configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: app-configmap
```

Finally below is the command I'm running in the pipeline:

```
helm upgrade --install testing deployment/helm/testing -f deployment/helm/testing/values.yaml --set known_hosts="***" --set image_name=$DOCKER_TAG
```

Comment: Try running `helm template deployment/helm/testing -f deployment/helm/testing/values.yaml --set known_hosts="***" --set image_name=$DOCKER_TAG`

Comment: @Bala when I do that I actually get no readout from the command line. When I run `helm list` it looks like nothing was installed either.

Comment: if you run `helm template` command it will generated the Kube config file by merging template and values files. In that way you should be able to debug much better.